Jetpack Compose Dialog FullScreen
I need a Full-screen dialog in Jetpack compose. It is working but there are status and navigation padding are showing. I need to fill that place with screen background colour.
Any solution? Thanks in advance!
Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismiss,   DialogProperties(
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
    ),) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White) // Background color for the dialog
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(
                        // Use insets to handle the status bar
                        top = WindowInsets.statusBars.asPaddingValues().calculateTopPadding()
                    ),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text("Your Dialog Content")
                Button(onClick = onDismiss) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    



Does this help?

@tomerpacific Not working!

This link : https://github.com/TheMelody/AnyPopDialog-Compose                                 https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.TheMelody/any_pop_dialog_compose/overview
